# $A$ subring of $B$, $p_2\subseteq p_1$ prime ideals in $A$ and $q_1$ prime ideal in $B$ such that $p_1=q_1\cap B$ then $p_2^e=B_{q_1}p_2$

Tags: commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, integral-dependence

I was reading Going Down Theorem from Atiyah-MacDonald. There is a theorem in the Rings and Modules of Fractions chapter

> ***Theorem 3.16***: Let $A\to B$ be a ring homomorphism and let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a prime ideal of $A$. Then $\mathfrak{p}$ is the contraction of a prime ideal $B$ if and only if $\mathfrak{p}^{ec}=\mathfrak{p}$

Now in the prove of going down theorem we have $\mathfrak{p}_1\supseteq \mathfrak{p}_2$ prime ideals in $A$ and a prime ideal $\mathfrak{q}_1$ in $B$ such that $\mathfrak{p}_1=\mathfrak{q}_1\cap A$. We want to find a prime ideal $\mathfrak{q}_2\subseteq \mathfrak{q}_1$ in $B$ such that $\mathfrak{p}_2=\mathfrak{q}_2\cap A$.

They want to show that $\mathfrak{p}_2$ is the contraction of a prime ideal in the ring $B_{\mathfrak{q}_1}$ or by the *Theorem 3.16* $$B_{\mathfrak{q}_1}\mathfrak{p}_2\cap A=\mathfrak{p}_2$$

Following the *Theorem 3.16* it means that the extension of $\mathfrak{p}_2$ in $B_{\mathfrak{q_1}}$ is $B_{\mathfrak{q}_1}\mathfrak{p}_2$. But i cant understand why that will be the case. Extension of $\mathfrak{p}_2$ in $B$ is $B\mathfrak{p}_2$. Then the prime ideal corresponding to $B\mathfrak{p}_2$ in $B_{\mathfrak{q}_1}$ is $(B\mathfrak{p}_2)_{\mathfrak{q}_1}$. Then why $$(B\mathfrak{p}_2)_{\mathfrak{q}_1}=B_{\mathfrak{q}_1}\mathfrak{p}_2$$

Also why then the contraction of $B_{\mathfrak{q}_1}\mathfrak{p}_2$ is just intersection with $A$.

Comment: The extension of $\mathfrak{p}_2$, which is a prime ideal of $A$, in $B_{\mathfrak{q}_1}$ is $B_{\mathfrak{q}_1}\mathfrak{p}_2$ by definition. The equality at the end of your post is true (both ideals are generated by $\mathfrak{p}_2$ in $B_{\mathfrak{q}_1}$), but you don't really need to know it. Also, contraction is intersection, because our ring map is an inclusion.